# Lets Encrypt SSL giving ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID for request towards node server

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I had installed a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on AWS instance, webserver is nginx, the application was working fine with it. However, it seems that there was a automatic update of certificate, and since then when I open my main site (say [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)), then the certificate is valid, however if I do login which sends a request to node server and the URL gets changed to say ([www.mysite.com:4041/auth/login](http://www.mysite.com:4041/auth/login)) then browser gives ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID and the browser says that certificate is expired. Please advise

I tried checking my installed certificate, but there the date is valid. Is there any settings which I am missing which is treating [www.mysite.com:4041/auth/login](http://www.mysite.com:4041/auth/login) as a different URL than [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and failing it. Is it I need to add wildcard somewhere?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache if doesn't work please check with solutions provided  on this link https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/net-err_cert_date_invalid/

Comment: I had checked this link earlier, it does not seem to be my local browser problem. All users who open my app are getting this error.

Comment: It works differently for  NGIX and node app, May be new certificates are not in effect for the port 4041 where node app is running. Please check the node configuration files(typically named as https_server.js or server.js) check if they are pointing to right cert files.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, node was pointing to wrong cert folder.

Comment: Happy to help, I'm writing same in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificate configuration works differently for NGIX and node app.

It seems new certificates are not in effect for the port 4041 where node app is running. Please check the node configuration files (typically named as https_server.js or server.js) check if they are pointing to right cert files or location.

For more details visit [How to Install an SSL Certificate on Node.js](https://www.ssldragon.com/how-to/install-ssl-certificate/node-js/)